# Anonymous posting

Tags: feature-request

Is it possible to post anonymously through my subscribed account and still track the answer properly? I recently did this by signing out, posting, then coming back onto my account, however, I was unable to edit the question later when some people had commented on it, since it was an unregistered account I posted with.

This board in particular would benefit from being able to post questions anonymously, but track them under your profile still. Thoughts?